Update Slices of Dynamic Eigen Matrix
I have an Eigen dynamically sized matrix that I'd like to update columnwise using another dynamic matrix (of the same shape), but I get a compile-time error. Is there a correct way to do this?
This is the function I'm working on:
#include "eigen.h"

using namespace Eigen;

MatrixXd sort_cols(const MatrixXd& mat, const VectorXd& order)
{
    int rows = mat.rows();
    int cols = mat.cols();

    MatrixXd ordered_mat(rows, cols);

    int dim = order.size();

    for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
    {
        ordered_mat(all, order(i)) = mat(all, i);
    }

    return ordered_mat;
}

I get a
error: request for member 'size' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'const double' EIGEN_CONSTEXPR Index size(const T& x) { return x.size(); }
and
 error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer return m_argImpl.coeffRef(m_xpr.rowIndices()[row], m_xpr.colIndices()[col]);
error unless I comment out ordered_mat(all, order(i)) = mat(all, i);

I ended up changing the line of code to ordered_mat.col(order(i)) = mat.col(i); and it works now, but I'm still not sure why my original code threw errors...

Your order vector consists of double. If you change the contained type to int (VectorXi) or do an explicit cast to int, the original works. The rest are just effects of overload resolution, templates etc. The workaround works because the col() method only accepts integers, so the compiler automatically converts from double to int

@Homer512 ah, that makes sense. Thanks!
